# How to read a .txt into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to read a .txt file via a Java program.

Say this is the text file `input.txt`

```
abc, test, 1,2,3
abc
abcd 
test, 1, 2, 3
```

Each line represents a row, each comma-separated value represents a column.

Currently my code is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    int num = readLines();  //this function just returns the number of lines
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        textData[i] = br.readLine();
    }
br.close();
```

This outputs the text file as it was shown above if I print the array. But I require to insert into the array split by comma(could be other character as well, just use comma for now). So this means the output will be such that `[abc,test,1,2,3],[abc],[abcd],[test,1,2,3]` in the array. How should I proceed?

**Thanks for the reply. Update:
Since i got my txt file into a array list,**

```
    [abc,test,1,2,3]
    [abc]
    [abcd]
    [test,1,2,3]
```

**How do i find the number of elements in each line?**

Comment: you need a collection but not arrays as lines has different length

Comment: Your problem is not clear. How is the output of your code different from the desired output?

Comment: Read the lines into an ArrayList (as pointed out by @getlost, your data is variable length, so the data struct should accommodate that requirement) and then, when you need to access each line, use your array list's .get() method to access each line as a String and use .split() directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array list of array lists:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
int lineCount = readLines();

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(lineCount);
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = br.readLine();
    for(String s: line.split(",")) {
        row.add(s);
    }
    rows.add(row);
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Im getting "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: I think that was happening because I was using the `[]` operator on an object of type `ArrayList`.  My Java is a little rusty! See my edits.